# Set background color based on user's text input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a text box where the user can type in one of the color key words such as blue, lime, or black, click submit, and the page background color will change accordingly.
Here is what I have:

```
<label for="color">Color: </label><input type="text" name="color" size="20" id="color" />
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:changeBGC(color)">Submit</button>
```

and then in my script

```
function changeBGC(color){
    document.bgColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('color').value;
```

`document.getElementById('color')` is the input element, `.value` gets it's value.

[Here's some more documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) on how to set css styles through JavaScript.

**[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mCMhw/1/)**

Comment: ... or if you have other background properties you want to keep intact (such as background image), make it `document.body.style.backgroundColor = color`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change markup to following:

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:changeBGC(color.value)">Submit</button>
                                                         ^
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R5TU3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a better approach

```
<label for="color">Color:</label>
<input type="text" name="color" size="20" id="color" value=""/>
<button type="button">Submit</button>

var input = document.getElementById('color');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();    
   var color = input.value;
   document.body.style.background = color;
});
```

Comment: `querySelector`? Why? And why would you declare that many temporary variables, like `var color`?

Comment: Why not no use `querySelector`? It's easier for me to read with temporary variables. Something like this: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8heY/)** Am I wrong or it's a bad way to code?

Comment: `querySelector` is _very_ inefficient. use `document.getElementsByTagName()` instead. Introducing many temporary variables like that is just asking for conflicts in large projects. I agree it's easier to read, but in my opinion, it's a bad habit. (Unless you use the temp var a lot in that function, then the code can be shortened by using it)